# How do I use a delegate with WorkflowApplication.OnUnhandledException

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, func

WF4 uses 4 Action that I can use to delegate to methods.  Like this.

```
_workflowApplication.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e) { WorkflowApplicationCompleted(e); };
```

However there are also 2 Func.  I can see how to use them inline but I want them to delegate to a method.

I tried:

```
_workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e) { WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle(e); };
```

but I have no return statement.

I tried:

```
_workflowApplication.OnUnhandledException = (returnValue) => WorkflowApplicationOnUnhandledException(e, returnValue);
```

but e does not resolve.

How can I delegate to a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void SetExceptionHandler(WorkflowApplication app)
{
    app.OnUnhandledException = x => HandleTheUnhandled(x);
}

private UnhandledExceptionAction HandleTheUnhandled(
    WorkflowApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    //some logic
    return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
}
```

Or

```
app.OnUnhandledException = x => 
{
    // some logic
    return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
};
```

Or, if no logic is required,

```
app.OnUnhandledException = x => UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
```

Lambdas.  Learn them.  Love them.